# event listener show/hide div that's populated from a loop

Tags: javascript, css, dom, addeventlistener

I have a forEach looping through a DB to print out the comments on a photo. each comment has an edit form with an edit and delete button. When the edit button is pressed it adds a class ".show" to the ".editForm". 
The problem is that this only works for the first comment when the edit button is clicked...it wont add the class .show to any other div(form) except the first instance.
Im trying to do this > when I click the edit button, show the form below the comments to be able to edit it.

CSS

```
.editForm {
    display: none;
}
.editForm.show{
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
document.querySelector(".editButton").addEventListener("click", function(){                                          
    document.querySelector(".editForm").classList.toggle("show"); 
});
```

See picture here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgi6M.jpg]

You can see that it worked for the first one. but for the second one if I look in the console, the button does nothing and is not adding the class...

---

Also, do i need to learn AJAX to be able to edit the comment "in place" ?? rather than opening a form > populating content > changing it > post route

Comment: i mean... your code [selects one element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and gives that one element an event handler. Did you intend to select more than one?

Comment: document.querySelector only selects the first instance. You need to use document.querySelectorAll then loop through the returned results.

Comment: @jeff i did what you said with the .editButton
I did querySelectorAll with the editButton, forEach, toggle show on the editForm, but now every edit button clicked just shows the first form for the first comment..

Comment: inside a function you need to specify that exactly form you need to show. Usually it ill be like this; $(this).getParents().find(".editForm").classList.toggle("show"); You should find a parent form from a button

Comment: Basically I want to toggle the class .show on the parent element div which is the form ... ive been looking for over a day on how to do this..sorry if im new

Comment: @volkinc this is refering to the editButton? I guess i should add jquery.

Comment: yes. the click event you connect to the buttons now the related form you should find from the button UP. in your case document.querySelector(".editForm").classList.toggle("show");  you saying select the first element from collections of the forms and upply the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector()` only returns the first matching element. You need to use `querySelectorAll()` to get all of them. It returns a `NodeList`, so you'll need to loop over it to process all of them. Then you'll need to use DOM traversal to find the related `.editForm` element.

My code below assums the `editButton` and `editForm` elements are both children in the same DIV. You might need to tweek it based on your actual HTML.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".editButton")).forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", function(){                                          
    this.parentNode.querySelector(".editForm").classList.toggle("show"); 
    })
);
```

If you decide to use jQuery, the equivalent is:

```
$(".editButton").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").find(".editForm").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

When you use a CSS class, javascript will usually only hit the first instance of that class, and then break on the rest. What you will probably need to do instead is to create unique ids for the html elements (you can add the style="display:none;" directly to the html element to avoid having to worry about the CSS file covering all possible ids), and then in JS as well. For example, if you were using PHP you could do something like this:

```
<?php foreach($db_row as $item): ?>
document.querySelector("#editButton-<?php echo $item['id'] ?>").addEventListener("click", function(){                                          
    document.querySelector("#editForm-<?php echo $item['id'] ?>").classList.toggle("show"); 
});
<?php endforeach; ?>
```